# Firefox ContextMenus.OnClick Event not firing, getting error

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Copy As",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds a right click option to quickly convert a macaddress and search ecoverage for an installation address.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["contextMenus","clipboardWrite"]
}
```

Background:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "conMacProv",
  title: "ProvisionLink MAC",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "conMacDev",
  title: "DevStat MAC",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "conWimaxStarQ",
  title: "Wimax - StarQuality",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "conHex",
  title: "Hex",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
  console.log(info);
  console.log("test");
});
```

Menu items are created but clicking the items doesn't yield console logs.
I'm using FF 56.0.1

> Disregard following:
>
> Also this script gives the following console error:
>
> > Empty string passed to getElementById().  main.7d260b3049ff.js:2:7526

Comment: Ok I understand now that the error is related to running on mozilla developer site only. So that probably isn't related to why the onClicked event isn't working

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your listener like this:

```
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    console.log("Item " + info.menuItemId + " clicked " +  "in tab " + tab.id);
});
```